# How can I add the date of the data that satisfies a condition in ifelse in R?

Tags: r, datetime, if-statement, difftime

I need to date and time of the data that satisfies a condition in ifelse.

```
Glucose_4h <- character()
for(i in 1:96){
A <- unlist(difftime(Time_Meal[i], Time_Glucose[1:15372], units="mins"))
B <- ifelse(as.numeric(A)>0 & as.numeric(A)<5.0, "Inc_G","Exc_G")
Glucose_4h <- c(Glucose_4h,B)
}
```

In this code I also need which Time_Glucose satisfied the condition
Could you help me about this?

Comment: Can you share sample data? ```dput(head(Time_Meal))``` and ```dput(head(Time_Glucose))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need the values of `Time_Glucose` where `Glucose_4h` is equal to `"Inc_G"`?  In your example `B` will always be 15372 long (the length of `Time_Glucose`.  You could then capture that along with what you're currently doing:

```
res <- NULL
for(i in 1:96){
  A <- unlist(difftime(Time_Meal[i], Time_Glucose[1:15372], units="mins"))
  B <- ifelse(as.numeric(A)>0 & as.numeric(A)<5.0, "Inc_G","Exc_G")
  res <- rbind(res, data.frame(obs = i, Glucose_4h = B, Time_Glucose = Time_Glucose))
}
```

Then, if you only want the ones where `Glucose_4h == "Inc_G"`, you could do the following:

```r
res[which(res$Glucose_4h == "Inc_G"), ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! You are lifesaver... Only, the second code didn't work so I used "filter" function and it worked.